# How to generate APK file from source in my app programmatically

Tags: php, android, asp.net

**For PHP:**

I have a project to create app like APK creator lite. I want to know how can I create APK file from my Android app using Java programmatically. I have search a lot about this but could not found any straight-forward way.
Basically task is that I have required Apk Name, Icon Url, WebView Url and Version in editText. Now I want to create APK from my app as user provided input Data.

**For Asp.net:**

I'm working on a project that will use asp.net and Android. First Client will fill data in the form and send to server on asp.net. When Data will be received then there will be a package of android drawable, layout, Java classes,manifest.xml etc. Then programmatically will modify icon,version No and URL of package.When everything will be done then

Here is my main problem,I want to create (APK) file. How can I do this? I tried it using gradle build.

Comment: Do you want to make something like http://www.android-ide.com/ ?

Comment: ApkGenerator web2app like this bro :(

Comment: http://lite-en-26.apkcreator.ca/ check this URL like that

Comment: Your question is very confusing then. I thought you want to compile java code on an android device and create an apk from it on the device. Please clarify your question, probably remove android, and certainly android-layout tags.

Comment: yes I want to create APK file on an android device and compile java code on an device please help :( :( :)

Comment: After I fixed the case errors in your question, and removed the requests for urgency you've made of volunteers here, did you just add that all back in, Arslan?

Comment: :( I'm having project from my boss connfused Now

Comment: Look this makes no sense. 1st decide what you want to do: create an apk in the web server or in the android device. Then EDIT your question to make this decision clear! Then include all the code relevant to your problem (build.gradle, maybe java code depending on your choice), then post also all error messages you get.

Comment: in android device will be difficult so I decide to jump on web using php with gradlew.bat but with command prompt apk creating but with php file throwing error below my comments given about it

Comment: I'm blocked so can't post bro

Comment: If your account is blocked from asking questions, [please read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: any budy here for help :P

Comment: Your last edit, when you split the question into two by asking both about php and asp is not a good step. Keep 1 SO question to 1 problem. This is not how it works: ask 1 Q, but then when it's solved, instead of going on, edit the question to your next problem. I already told this before 2 days ago

Comment: @Gavriel: when a problem is solved, the user should certainly not change it to another problem. We call these "chameleon questions" - they are a pain because they make existing answers redundant, and require an editor to clean up the mess. New questions should go in a new post (and if the OP is blocked then they should become unblocked before posting again).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an apk in your webserver, then you should have a "template" android project on your webserver. When the user fills in the form with he's email, name, etc, you COPY the whole template directory to a temporary directory and in that directory save the input to a java file or to an android xml file depending how you want to use it prom the android project. Then you simply execute `gradlew build` in the directory, and send the apk to the user.

From php:

```
echo system('JAVA_HOME=' . escapeshellarg('C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin')
   . ' PATH=' . escapeshellarg('C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin'
   . PATH_SEPARATOR . getenv('PATH'))
   . ' C:\xampp\htdocs\project\FirstProject\gradlew.bat assembledebug')
```

Of course JAVA_HOME and PATH will need to have the values according to where you installed it.

If you want to do it in the android device then try: https://github.com/t-arn/java-ide-droid

Comment: Bro How will i run this gradle on server when website will be uploaded on cpanel or testing on 000host

Comment: helo Bro gradle is not executing via php

Comment: gadlew build not exxecuting via php

Comment: @Arslan: I doubt you can run this on a cPanel shared Linux host - you will need a Linux VPS for this. You can get one for 1USD per month, or there are a few hosts that will do trial packages of cloud VPS accounts - you might be able to use a free one permanently.

Comment: He said it works from command line. The only problem is to get the call right, but it's nearly impossible to help someone who's not wanting to be helped... He's not posting the error messages...

Comment: @Gavriel: please use people's nick to draw attention to comments directed to them, e.g. `@halfer` - I saw your message to me by accident. I agree that the question is unclear and features no effort/research - I have cast a close vote.